# Get folder size of user HomeDirectory using CSV file

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have a CSV file with user IDs and a script that already pulls the UNC path to the HomeDirectory, I'm hoping to query to pull the size of the user HomeDirectory and then add it to the CSV file. This is what I currently have:

```
$userlist = Import-Csv "C:\HomeShares\NToU.csv"
```

ForEach ($user in $userlist) {

$SamID_User = $user.NID

#A Search by SamAccountName

$result = Get-ADUser -Filter { samaccountname -eq $SamID_User } -Properties HomeDirectory |

Select-Object samaccountname,HomeDirectory

$result | Export-CSV "C:\HomeShares\new_names.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append

}

Could someone please point me in the right direction on how to add in getting the folder size? I have researched the possibility of using RoboCopy to get this but I would need to use the new CSV file to do the source? Or is there an easier way in the existing ForEach loop?

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

```sh
"{0} GB" -f [math]::Round(((Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1GB), 2)
```

where `$sourcePath` is the path to ie. `C:\users\jdoe\`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this where you pull in the records from your csv, pipe them to `ForEach-Object`, grab the matching account from AD using `Get-ADUser`, use `Get-ChildItem` to find all the files recursively in the user's home directory and finally use `Measure-Object` to sum up the length/size.

```
Import-Csv 'C:\HomeShares\NToU.csv' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$($_.NID)'" -Properties HomeDirectory |
            ForEach-Object {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    SamAccountName           = $_.SamAccountName
                    HomeDirectory            = $_.HomeDirectory
                    'HomeDirectorySize (GB)' = $(
                        '{0:f2}' -f ((Get-ChildItem $_.HomeDirectory -File -Recurse | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum / 1GB)
                    )
                }
            }
        } | Export-Csv 'C:\HomeShares\new_names.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite some time for this but I wanted to post the script that I ended up using that works great!

```
GetHomeDriveSize.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
           [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0)]
           [string]$File,
           [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=1)]
           [string]$ExportFile
)

$IDs = (Import-Csv -Path $File).NID
Foreach ($ID in $IDS) {
           $Size = ''
           $DataError = ''
           Try {
                          Write-Verbose "Checking $ID"
                          $User = Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$ID'" 
-Properties 'HomeDirectory' | Select-Object SamAccountName, HomeDirectory
                          $Name = $User.SamAccountName
                          $Directory = $User.HomeDirectory
                          If ($Null -ne $Directory) {
                                         Write-Verbose "Home for $Name is 
$Directory"
                                         If (Test-Path -Path $Directory) {
                                                        $Size = '{0:f2}' -F 
((Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -File -Recurse | Measure-Object Length - 
Sum).Sum / 1KB)
                                         } Else {
                                                        $Message = "Can't access 
$Directory"
                                                        Write-Warning $Message
                                                        $DataError = $Message
                                         }
                                         Write-Verbose "Size of Home for $Name 
is $Size"
                          } Else {
                                         $Message = "No home directory found for 
$Name"
                                         Write-Warning $Message
                                         $DataError = $Message
                          }
           } Catch {
                          $Message = "AD properties not retrieved for $Name"
                          Write-Warning $Message
                          $DataError = $Message
           }
           [PSCustomObject]@{
                          SamAccountName = $User.SamAccountName
                          HomeDirectory  = $User.HomeDirectory
                          'Size (KB)'    = $Size
                          Error          = $DataError
           } | Export-Csv -Path $ExportFile -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).